# having an issue to call Javascript function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have a Datepicker for Bootstrap and I am having an issue to run a function called "listCampaignsFiltered(search, type, from, 'dataTable')" that filters the results once I click on any date from the calendar. Here is the code:

Html

```
<div id="showfrom">
<label for="from" class="filter">From:
<input type="text" class="filter" value="01/01/2014" id="from"/>
</label>    
</div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showbrand input').val(01/01/2014).click(listCampaignsFiltered);
});
```

Comment: "from jQuery"? jQuery *IS* JavaScript.

Comment: Shouldn't your date in the val() have quotes around it?

Comment: That was one issue.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The call val(01/01/2014) would set the value to 1 divided by 1 divided by 2014. You are missing quotes.
- Are you sure you always want to set the date back to 01/01/2014? If so use the commented out line instead of the line bellow it.
- Next listCampaignsFiltered has be be defined and without error. I am assuming it works and you've tested it independently of the listner.
- Next, to pass the values into it, you need wrap the function in an lambda/anonymous function.
- I am also assuming that the values for function are all in inputs with the ids matching the parameters you gave in your post.

Here is what you end up with, with those changes:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  /*$('#showbrand input').val('01/01/2014').click(function()*/
  $('#showbrand input').click(function()
  {
    listCampaignsFiltered
    (
      $('#search').val(),
      $('#type').val(),
      $('#from').val(),
      'dateTable'
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted.. It finally worked I had to fix something on my php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The proper form would be:

```
  $('#showbrand input').val('01/01/2014').on('click', function() {
   listCampaignsFiltered(...params....)
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this is what you intended

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#showbrand input').val('01/01/2014').on('click', function()
 listCampaignsFiltered(param1,param2,param3,param4);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`jsfiddle.net/JixunMoe/29wBy/`

Not sure if that's what you want, but the callback works as expected (for me).

Comment: Worked! had to fix a php file... Thanks a lot!